# Using Visual Studio (Isolated Shell?) to program ARM device

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, gcc

I want to use Visual Studio (maybe Isolated Shell) to create a custom IDE for programming a custom ARM-based device in C.  The device has no OS and is being used like a microcontroller.

[Atmel's AVR Studio 5](http://xtronic.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Atmel-AVR-Studio-5.png) uses the Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell and I would like to do something similar.  I am currently using a gcc-based ARM compiler.

I've already been through [MSDN's documentation for extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165), but I can't find anything specific to this task.  Can someone give me an idea of how to approach this?  For example, is there some way for me to leverage the Visual C++ editor without having to use Babel to re-teach Visual Studio about C?

Comment: I've had this idea myself and the direction I was going to start looking at is to create custom MSBuild tasks. You could then hopefully make the MSBuild task call into your embedded compiler instead of the c# or C++ compiler. I'm not sure how you would get anything like intellisense or syntax highlighting to work though.

Comment: The Isolated Shell has a lot of technical and licensing limitations. For example, it does not have Source Control, and it does not have all well-known VS editors, like the C#, C++, etc. Many existing VSDK samples (like IronPython) do not target the isolated shell and simply assume you're working off a "regular" Visual Studio, in MSDN and on the Internet. Even the limitation itself are not clearly documented and will be found the hard way. Other than this, MSDN is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN documentation is not enough if you want to create a new IDE in fact. My personal suggestion is that you learn from existing large samples, such as this Python IDE,

http://pytools.codeplex.com/

It is designed by Microsoft, so it provides much useful information that does not appear in MSDN.

However, reusing Visual C++ editor means you cannot use only Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell (I think), as that may require some assemblies that only full Visual Studio has.